# Return IAsyncEnumerable with Azure Functions on .NET 8 Isolated

Tags: .net-8.0, azure-functions-isolated

I am trying to return an `IAsyncEnumerable<MyObject>` with Azure Functions `HttpTrigger`, using .NET 8 Isolated Process.

When I return the type I get the following error message:

> .IAsyncEnumerable' can only be serialized using async serialization methods.
>
> at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException_TypeRequiresAsyncSerialization(Type propertyType)
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IAsyncEnumerableOfTConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TAsyncEnumerable value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, etc.

Does anyone know how I can tell the Azure Function to use the `SerializeAsync` method for a specific function?

-- Update --

So after looking deeper into this I have found this question on learn.microsoft.com

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1418946/in-the-azure-functions-isolated-process-model-how

Where the question is being asked about streaming in azure functions.

which points to an existing issue on github around the gRPC proxy layer being the issue in that the whole body needs to be serialised before it is sent to the client.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1387

At the bottom of this issue the comments point to the fact azure functions now uses asp net core integration which should solve this issue

> fabiocav commented on May 23, 2023 @rodolfograve I'll continue
> providing updates on that thread.
>
> Updating here that the initial preview of the work tracked by this
> epic is now in preview:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#aspnet-core-integration-preview

However there is still no example on that thread for streaming, I will try and contact @fabiocav but would be nice to know if this has been solved.

This feels like a bit of a step backwards as at least with .NET6 in-process with V2 Compatibility mode I could return a `HttpResponseMessage` with `PushStreamContent` and this was working/streaming fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, Azure Functions now supports using the ASP.NET Core integration. [Microsoft Learn provides a small guide on how to enable this in your function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#aspnet-core-integration).

Follow their setup and you're good to go with the integration. Now you can work with [HttpResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse) objects which allow you to stream your response.

A small example:

```cs
    [Function("YourFunction")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "your/route")]
        HttpRequest req)
    {
        IAsyncEnumerable<YourDataClass> data = getABunchOfData();

        var response = req.HttpContext.Response;
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";

        await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(response.Body, data);

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Happy streaming!